# If $A = BQ^T$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, then is $\text{Col}(A) = \text{Col}(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I have to find a reduced SVD, A = U<sub>r</sub>DV<sub>r</sub><sup>T</sup>, for the matrix A = BQ<sup>T</sup>.

They give me the matrix B and the null-space of $A$. I've already found the singular values for A and the matrix V<sub>r</sub> (with an orthonormal basis of row space of A) but I'm not so sure about how to find a basis for Col(A).

Is saying that Col(A) is the same as Col(B) correct? If so, why?

Comment: Does Col refer to the range space?

Comment: I think what you are saying is that you know $ A $, $ D $, and $ V_r $.  But since $ A = U_r D V_r^T $ you should be able to manipulate this to find $ U_r $ in terms of $ A $, $ D $, and $ V_r $.  Once you have $ U_r $, you have a basis for $ {\rm Col}( A ) $.

Comment: For your second question, if you have the reduced SVD for $ A$, it is easy to find the reduced SVD for $ B $.  If you understand how to extract a basis for the column space of $ A $ from the reduced SVD, then you will have your answer.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, the column space of A.

Comment: @ulaff.net I don't know A. The only known matrix is B.

Comment: Ah.  My comments can be easily converted to that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we have ${\cal R} (MN) \subset {\cal R}M$.

Hence we have ${\cal R} (B Q^TQ) \subset {\cal R} (B Q^T) \subset{\cal R} B$ and since
$Q^TQ=I$ we have the desired result.